# where should I put .gitignore to affect all projects?

Tags: git, egit

where should I place a `.gitignore` file so that all my projects use those settings?

I tried various folders and I can only get it to work if I put it in my project folder, but then the settings (of course) only are applied to that project... not my other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **command line**. The reason is, that you need to place the gitignore file in the parent directory of your Eclipse projects, but you cannot see that directory in the Eclipse workbench (as Eclipse projects are top level entities there).

E.g. you have 2 Eclipse projects, which are stored like this in your repository

\mygitrepo\project1

\mygitrepo\project2

then just add the .gitignore file in the mygitrepo directory.

Answer (score 13):

git include a "global" configuration option which can tell it to include the files you want to ignore always when you start a project. Example, if the compilation of your ignore files is called: ignore_global, you could do this;

```
git config --global core.excludesfile /path/to/your/ignore_global
```

more about it at here: [Ignore Files](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/)

Answer (score 5):

Even though the previous solutions work, I would recommend having a global `~/.gitignore_global` and adding it to your exclude files with the command:

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`.

This is the recommended solution by github: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Answer (score 0):

It is not eclipse specific. Try this: http://programblings.com/2008/10/22/git-global-ignores/

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the commandline.

1. Open Window->Preferences
2. Select Team->Git-Configuration
3. Switch to `User Settings` tab.
4. Click `Add Entry ...` and enter `core.excludesfile` as key and `~/.gitignore` as value
5. Open `~/.gitignore` and add all your to-ignore-patterns inside the `.gitignore`

I.e:

```
target
.*
```

6. Restart eclipse