# Where does the default Visual Studio 2013 .gitignore reside?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

So awhile ago I noticed that Visual Studio was automatically creating a .gitignore file whenever I created a solution inside an existing local git repo folder.  Great.  However, I noticed it was ignoring some NCrunch files (*.ncrunchsolution and *.ncrunchproject) that should really be in source control.  So I decided to dig in to fix it.  The problem here is I don't know where it's getting this default file from.  I see that it's basically an older version of [VisualStudio.gitignore at the gitignore GitHub project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) (which just so happened to fix the NCrunch issue [back in April](https://github.com/github/gitignore/commit/d6ffb3cac30c0b338dadebfb13e1403a4029da61#diff-07fccc01505e9b231e926168fc909197)).

Where can I find or configure the source for the .gitignore that the Visual Studio git provider automatically puts into a git repo?

(**Edit**: I looked at [the ignore topic what I assume are the official docs for the VS 2013 git functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967655.aspx#ignore), but it doesn't help to find a system-wide setting for this.  It simply mentions "the default .gitignore file provided by Visual Studio" without any mention of how to modify this file.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `.GitIgnore` is an Embedded Resource of

```
// Assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices, Version 12.0.0.0

Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.dll 
Name: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 
Type: Library 

// public resource Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.Resources.VS.gitignore
```

So I don't think you can update it.

It was recently updated with Visual Studio 2013u2, but it seems the `ncrunch` files are still part of the default ignores. I suspect that a newer version will be included in 2013u3 or maybe as an interim update. Until then, you'll need to manually patch your `gitignore` files or [create a default gitignore in your userprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415908/736079).